# Passing parameters to redirect_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a controller to register a new employee on the system, and in this controller I need a verification to ensure that both the inserted email and the CPF (brazilian document) are unique and not yet registered. I'm trying to use redirect_to to return to the form:

```
def create
    @model = Employee.new(employee_params)
    @model.cpf_plain = employee_params[:cpf].gsub('-', '').gsub('.', '')
    @model.activated = true
    if Employee.where(email: @model.email).first.present? || Employee.where(cpf_plain: @model.cpf_plain).present?
      redirect_to new_employee_url(employee: employee_params), notice: 'Já existe um Otto com este email ou CPF'
      return
    end

    if @model.save
      @model.generateTempPass
      redirect_to employees_url, notice: 'Otto criado com sucesso.'
    else
      redirect_to new_employee_url(employee: employee_params),
                  notice: 'Não foi possível salvar este Otto no momento, tente novamente mais tarde.'
    end
end
```

But I can't figure out how to return to the form keeping the already filled fields. I've tried using render instead of return_to:

```
if Employee.where(email: @model.email).first.present? || Employee.where(cpf_plain: @model.cpf_plain).present?
      render create, notice: 'Já existe um Otto com este email ou CPF'
      return
end
```

But for some reason I enter in a infinite loop where the controller keep doing the verification of email and CPF over and over again.

Comment: You probably need to render the  `new` action instead of the `create` one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Dan's comment is right, you need to render new, not create.

```rb
if Employee.where(email: @model.email).any? || Employee.where(cpf_plain: @model.cpf_plain).present?
  render :new, notice: 'Já existe um Otto com este email ou CPF' and return
end
```

(i changed 'first.present?' and shortened the render to one line, too)

Comment: Thanks, it worked fine! The only exception was the notice, it stopped working, I searched about it and apparently with render you need to use `flash[:notice]` before it.